# Symbolic name as type constructor

Tags: haskell

Sorry, a newbie's question about Haskell...

What do I have to do to use an infix-symbol as a type constructor? I've found the following piece of code, but ghc and ghci complain "Unexpected type `~>' where type variable expected"...

```
class Category (~>) where
(.) :: (a ~> b) -> (b ~> c) -> (a ~> c)
id  :: a ~> a
```

How can this be done? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can't have a symbol as a type variable (or a regular variable).

Comment: It found this piece of code in this article https://tailcalled.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/translation-of-monads-are-just-monoids-in-the-category-of-endofunctors/... So is it only pseudo-code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of GHC 7.6, [all `TypeOperators` are always constructors](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html). I'm not sure why this is, but I guess this breaking change is to avoid breaking even older code. [More info in the mailing list.](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-September/022845.html)

Comment: Umm, I think the breaking change was to make syntax for type-level programming (like type families) nicer. Very few people used infix type variables, but with the new facilities there's a lot of uses for infix types.

Comment: Indeed, infix type variables are kind of silly, as type variables are always local; it would be a shame to waste a nice namespace to support them. Doesn't this break the correspondence between type and data constructors? Or are data constructors also changed?

Answer (score 0):

Infix type constructors need to begin with a `:`. Try rewriting your code to use `:~>`

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html

Comment: This is not a type constructor; it's a type variable. I don't see why it doesn't work as written.

Comment: @dfeuer: I guess your interpretation of the code is correct but the question title and question text talk about defining new type constructors. Maybe OP can expand a bit to clear up this confusion?

Comment: Well, at least I don't know which extension I have to use to get it work as written. ghc tells me that -fglasgow-exts is deprecated...

Comment: They screwed up the documentation. Since 7.6, [all type operators are constructors](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html), even though the more specific documentation [says a leading `:` decides it](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#infix-tycons).